# Why do I get stubbing problem when using eq on generated class

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I m using rest template

```
String urlTemplate = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(dxiFindBatchUrl)
                .queryParam("codes", "{codes}")
                .queryParam("supplierName", "{supplierName}")
                .queryParam("limit", "{limit}")
                .encode()
                .toUriString();

        Map<String, String> params = Map.of("codes", String.join(",", sourceIds),
                "supplierName", supplierName,
                "limit", String.valueOf(sourceIds.size()));
ResponseEntity<PartFindResultModelApi> findResult = apxRestTemplate.getForEntity(urlTemplate, PartFindResultModelApi.class, params);
```

in test

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForEntity(Mockito.anyString(), eq(PartModelApi.class), Mockito.anyMap()))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(partModel, HttpStatus.OK));
```

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'getForEntity' method:
    restTemplate.getForEntity(
    "http://localhost:8080?codes={codes}&supplierName={supplierName}&limit={limit}",
    class de.kumasoft.datahub.ebay.automativeparts.api.model.PartFindResultModelApi,
    {"limit" = "1", "codes" = "123", "supplierName" = "TestSupplier"}
);
    -> at de.kumasoft.datahub.ebayservice.service.clients.apx.AutomativePartsClient.findParts(AutomativePartsClient.java:43)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. restTemplate.getForEntity("", null, {});
```

I think the null might be issue in stubbing but what can I do about it?

Comment: You search for `PartFindResultModelApi `, but mock for `PartModelApi `